# Can get() retrieve full html after that page's scripts finish adjusting it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to perform an AJAX GET on a page and retrieve the final version of the HTML on that page after all of its own scripts have finished adjusting its contents?

Right now if I perform a GET on a page with scripts that are adding to the HTML, it'll give me the full HTML as it was before that extra content was added.

So if there's a javascript generating a specific table on that page, it wouldn't be returned by the GET.  Because it didn't exist before that page's scripts generated it.

How can you `get()` the finished product of a page's HTML, after anything on that page altered it?

Comment: No, you can't do this with ajax, which is for communicating with a server. The work done by JavaScript happens in the client browser.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to handle the modifications in the file with a server side language (PHP f.e.)?

Comment: @Pieter the question is about pages that use client-side code to create/modify content, I think.

Comment: @Pointy Yeah, I got that, but I wonder whether that creation/modification can't be done with server-side code (in that file). An Ajax request suggests the use of a server-side language.

Comment: @Pointy You're right.  I tried to specify as much as I could but realize it may have been confusing.  Could you elaborate on what you mean, Pointy? 

If I understand you correctly, you're saying that because scripts are activated upon browsing the page it's impossible to retrieve their HTML adjustment, because they never exist serverside?

Comment: @Bicara An Ajax request will be handled on the server. All client-side code (like Javascript) will be handled by the browser, so it will not show up when you request it by using Ajax.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Thanks for the info.  Unfortunately with that in mind I suppose the mission I'm trying to embark on may have been doomed from the start.

Comment: @Bicara yes, that's exactly right - those changes that happen in the client are completely unknown to the server.

Comment: @Bicara If what you want is the finished text, you can drop the response in the DOM which will cause the javascript to run (& modify the page) and then get the contents with jQuery

Comment: @yoelp I'm not quite sure what you mean.  I'm pretty new to jQuery/javascript in general, sorry to be a burden.  By "Drop the response in the DOM", what exactly do you want me to do? Just print out the response instead of the data element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A AJAX call will only return what the server sent back,
But what you can do is Drop the response (data) in the DOM and that will cause javascript to run, and then you can take out the content with jQuery, 
**See Bellow:**

```
$.get("data.html",function(data){
  //insert the response in a hidden div that will cause js to run and apply changes
  var $container = $("<div>").html(data);
  var newData = $container.html();
  //newData will hold the final html 
});
```

Note: The actual `script` element will not be in `newData`.

Hope this helps